# Deleting content of Internal Storage file in android

Tags: android

I have created a file for storing important data from my application , at the press of a button i want to clear data from that file without deleting it;I am using MODE_APPEND to append the data from my application.Please do suggest.

Comment: delete the file and create the blank file with same name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19043609/1318946

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
       PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
       writer.print("");
       writer.close();
```

this will print empty string in the file